# Ubuntu 16.40 LTS -- How do I get a GUI feedback on an ongoing search process

Tags: gui, search

This is about Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I wanted to search for a file by part of the name using the GUI.

There is no GUI indication that the search is in progress (i.e. when it *is* actually doing it).  As I said, I am new to Linux... but (normatively speaking) the fact that there is no sign of a search processing should mean that it is not.  Indeed it was not, but there is no feedback when it *is*.  I do not know whether or not there is any feedback when it finishes; it is a very safe bet that there is not.

Is there any way to get a GUI-feedback when there is a search in progress?

p.s.  I just want to note that this is radically different from my original post; I do not have this question.  (I do not imagine that I can add content to the graphical user interface of an OS.)

Comment: @Takkat:  I am not angry with you if you were simply trying to help.  *Very sorry*.  It is just that I have repeatedly had posts radically edited, closed and deleted entirely, without recourse on my part... by people who refused to discuss the issue.  Kudos to you for replying.

Comment: I have rolled back to the previous version.  This basically distills the original to more of a question and answer type format that the site likes.  It is easier to read and is more amenable to answer.

Comment: @fossfreedom:  Again, as you have edited it, the original meaning is completely destroyed.  Put it back the way it was, if you do not have the wherewithal to read and understand it.  At the very least (if you understood it) you could render what I *did write* as a question.

Comment: ... or, as I hope was apparent originally, I am happy for someone to delete this entirely, on the basis that it is not apt -- provided they treat me as a human being in the process.

Answer (score 1):

A search for a file based on part of a name would take less than a second using:

```
locate part-of-name
```

Note do ***not*** use `*` before or after `part-of-name` search string.

There is a preliminary step required to include files added today and exclude files deleted today. `sudo updatedb` must be run in this situation.

I can easily create a GUI solution using `zenity` that calls the `locate` command from the desktop.

Because it takes about 1 second to find the matching files out of 2 million file name on Ubuntu and two Windows 10 partitions on my system a progress indicator is unnecessary.

Comment: My search (when it was working) was still adding items after about 10 seconds.  As I said in my original post, the root issue was that the search was not happening -- very anomalously -- and there is absolutely no feedback.  Anyway, it is all history now.

Answer (score 0):

## 16.04

There is a search indicator in default Unity settings of Ubuntu 16.04. It is a bit hidden but still there. We might not see it because the search is usually finished faster than we are able to recognize the indicator.

Below they are shown for searches that took long enough for me to take a screenshot:

### Dash:

[image] Searching  [image] Done

### Nautilus:

[image]

Search indicator on bottom right

---

## 18.04

In Ubuntu 18.04. the default desktop environment canged to GNOME. The nautilus search indicator is unchanged from above. An ongoing search from the "activities" menu is indicated like this:

[image]

---

When on Ubuntu then unlike a closed source OS we are of course able to add our own indicators to the graphical user interface. No magic involved but perhaps we need a bit of coding skills. That is the whole point of running an Open Source OS.